# Excel vba: Find function with additional conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have this table where I'm supposed to get the "Applicability" of each element of category "3" knowing **Only** its Id.
[image]

Example: findAppl(0709_2014)="Yes"

Here is my code:

```
Function findAppl(id As Range)
Set t1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1")
Set ids = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ids") 
Set id = ids.find(id.value, LookIn:=xlValues)


If Not IsEmpty(table.Rows(id.Row - 1).value) Then
findAppl = t1.Rows(id.Row - 1).value
End if
End Function
```

The problem is that the find function always returns the first range with the id given, which corresponds to a range with category=2. To resolve this, I set an if condition after the find function but the code doesn't work anymore, I alse used the option 'After :=' but it doesn't seem to work properly

P.S. the applicability do not depend on the category
for each id we can have one or two categories

Comment: Should put this as a comment than as an answer... use `=worksheetfunction.vlookup()` in your VBA function ans pass the Range as input. That should get the job done. Otherwise, you can always loop through the range internally and return the output.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which uses for loop. you can use this if the number of rows are not much...

```
Sub Test()
lrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
For cel = 1 To lrow
    If Cells(cel, 3) = "yes" And Cells(cel, 2) = 3 Then
        MsgBox Cells(cel, 1)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

please find the simple loop which uses the find function instead of loop through all the cells...hope this works for you...

```
    Sub test()
With Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B500")
    Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues) 'give the category value here ex:2
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        If Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = "yes" Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                MsgBox Range(c.Address).Offset(0, -1)                    
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If c Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And (c.Address <> firstAddress)
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "get".  But you can certainly use the autofilter to return the values you want.  The following code, using your data, puts the results next to your table.  You could put it on another sheet, another location, into a VBA array, or wherever:.  Obviously, you'll need an input routine for your ID and Category to find.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindApp()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Const Category As Long = 2
    Const ID As String = "0709_2014"
    Dim rTable As Range
Set WS = ActiveSheet

Set rTable = Range("Table1")
    rTable.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=ID
    rTable.AutoFilter 2, Category

Range("g1:I1").EntireColumn.Clear
    rTable.Rows(0).Copy Range("g1")
    rTable.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("g2")

rTable.AutoFilter 'Turn off autofilter

End Sub
```